# How does conditionVariable.await() work in a Java monitor class

Tags: java, multithreading

When a thread inside a monitor object calls the method conditionVariable.await(), I read that the global mutex lock is unlocked in the monitor object. But which queue is prioritized when the lock is unlocked? Because you both have a mutex queue, with all threads that are waiting outside the monitor and you also have the other conditionVariable queue. So when the mutex lock is unlocked, then which thread gets access to the object, the first thread in the mutex queue outside the object or the first thread in the conditionVariable queue? Which queue is prioritized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the monitor locks and conditions in `java.util.concurrent.locks`.

In general, the answer is that threads attempting the lock the monitor from the "outside" and threads being awakened from conditions attempting to lock the monitor from the "inside" all contend for the lock, and the order or fairness (or lack thereof) of threads acquiring the monitor lock is determined by the particular lock implementation.

The specification for [ReentrantLock.newCondition](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#newCondition--) says

> The ordering of lock reacquisition for threads returning from waiting
>   methods is the same as for threads initially acquiring the lock, which
>   is in the default case not specified, but for *fair* locks favors those
>   threads that have been waiting the longest.

The `ReentrantLock` has an optional boolean that determines the fairness of the lock at construction time. Note that setting the fairness parameter doesn't *guarantee* a particular thread ordering, it just attempts to make it more fair (at the expense of performance).